# Google Apps Script cache stopped working today

Tags: google-apps-script

I used Google Apps Script Cache's putAll() for 21600 seconds.  It has been working for months today just stopped working - all get from cache return null.  The script reads a .csv file with about 90K entries, remove unwanted chars then caches using putAll() method.  I tested the same file with the same script in my Dev's project it works fine.  So somehow it does not work in my Production project.  The code exactly the same, below:

My production's project id: Vendor Retainer GAS - project-id-5629958634838222671

There is no errors reported.

```
function cacheVendorList() {

  var dataFilesFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(dataFileFolderId);
  var fileIt = dataFilesFolder.getFilesByName("VendorFile.csv");
  if (fileIt != null && fileIt.hasNext()) {
    var vendorFile = fileIt.next();
    var keyValueStr = "{" + vendorFile.getAs(MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT).getDataAsString().
    replace(/SAP,NAME,CMPY,CURRENCY/,'99,Test').
    replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ,\n]/g,' ').
    replace(/$/mg,'",').
    replace(/^\d+,/mg, 
            function(x) {                      
              return '"' + x.substring(0,x.length-1) + '": "';
            }).
    replace(/D ",\n",$/,'D "') + "}";

    //dataFilesFolder.createFile("VendorFile.txt", keyValueStr, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT);

    //Logger.log(keyValueStr);
    var keyValObj = eval("(" + keyValueStr + ")");

    // create a new vendor cache
    vendorCache.putAll(keyValObj, 21600); // 21600 cache it for 6 hours

     Logger.log("0000010100: " + vendorCache.get("0000010100"));  
    Logger.log("0090000435: " + vendorCache.get("0090000435")); 

    Logger.log("Got it");

  }

}
```

Comment: Please post your code snippet.

Comment: Are you caching the proper type? Only `String` is allowed.

Comment: The script is very complex.  It reads .csv file with about 90K entries, remove some unwanted chars and then use putAll() method to add them to cache.

Comment: Could it be due to quota issue on using Cache service ?  The cache is reset every 4 hours through trigger.  Thanks!

Comment: If there is a service disruption at Google, the first thing you need to check is the [G Suite Status Dashboard](https://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=status)  But, unless it's a large outage, I doubt that Google would report it.  The next issue would be your quota.  If you used up your quota, then it would stop working.  [Quotas for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)  And there is no method in the Cache Class to check the current quota status.  So, unfortunately, you may never know if it is a quota issue.

Comment: Unless this is an Apps Script bug, that you can reproduce somehow, I'm not sure if you'll ever get a definitive answer.  If this is on a free/consumer account, there is no support really.  And even you have a GSuite account, they don't really support Apps Script.  You could try making a copy of your script file, and see if the copy works.  Even if all that does it get it working again, that's better than nothing.

Comment: It looks like the replace method somehow insert newline for every 5000 lines or so.  That breaks my script.  This is new.  My script works just fine before